# PHP - MySQL - JS : How to combine dynamic row with autofill?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

i want to make some dynamic row. A column in each row need to load data from MySQL database and a column need to get the value from selected option.

This is what a row looks like:

Date | No | Supplier_Id | Supplier_Name | Qty | Price

Supplier_Name is a dropdown which get the list from MySQL database (`SELECT supplier_name FROM tblSupplier`).

Then, when i select one of the Supplier_Name, i want to get the id value of the Supplier_Name.

The PRIMARY KEY is Supplier_Id.

Is it possible to combine dynamic row with dropdown list(get list from MySQL database) and autofill(get the id value of selected name)?

Here's my code :

```
<tr>
<td>
    <input name="date" type="text" id="date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d", $now); ?>" maxlength="10" size="10" readonly/>
</td>
<td><input name="no" type="number" id="no[]" value="<?php echo $no; ?>"readonly/></td>
<td><input name="supplier_id" type="text" id="supplier_id[]" value="<?php echo $supplier_id; ?>"></td>

<td align="center"><select name="supplier_name">
            <?php
            while($suppl=mysql_fetch_array($s)){
            ?><option value=<?echo $suppl[0]?> selected> <?php echo $suppl[1];?></option>
            <?php } ?>

<td align="center"><input name="qty" type="number" size="10" maxlength="10"></td>
<td align="center"><input name="price" type="number" size="10" maxlength="10"></td>
</tr>
```

Thank you.

Comment: u want fill all inputs by qty and price and supplier_id when supplier name is selected ?

Comment: @peter no, i just want to fill the supplier_id, because qty and price is not included in tblSupplier. thanks in advance

Comment: can you provide me what is it this `$supplier_id` in your code ?and ur sql also

Comment: $supplier_id="SELECT supplier_id FROM tblSupplier"; and the SQL is CREATE TABLE tblSupplier(
 supplier_id varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY,
 supplier_name varchar(50)
); LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/xampp/htdocs/Workshop/tblSupplier.csv' 
INTO TABLE tblSupplier
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
ENCLOSED BY ''''
IGNORE 1 LINES;

Comment: Exact duplicate of [PHP MySQL : Can I combine dynamic row with autofill?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13787365/php-mysql-can-i-combine-dynamic-row-with-autofill).  **Stop posting the same question over and over with minor variations.**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to get the supplier id by using the session

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM tblSupplier"; 
$row = mysql_fetch_array ($sql);

session_start();
if ( isset($_POST['supplier_id'])) {
$supplier_id = $_POST['supplier_id'] ;
$_SESSION['supplier_id']= $_POST['supplier_id'];
 }else{$_SESSION['supplier_id']= $row['supplier_id'];}
```

and then replace by this line

```
 <td><input name="supplier_id" type="text" id="supplier_id[]" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['supplier_id']; ?>"/></td>
```

change

```
readonly
```

to

```
readonly="readonly"
```

Comment: does it getting the supplier_id when i click one of the supplier_name list in the dropdown?